# Mongodb start a local sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

Trying to set up a local sharded cluster for testing (mongo 3.6). There are a number of scripts online (e.g [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/leetreveil/7233677/raw/2a0ddc36d08b3e92e553592eed80856fb22fecec/start-mongo-replset.sh), [here](https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/34c9b48517004efce0545f8e07388c9f)) all of which seem to fail for me.

running (cribbed mostly from the 2nd example above):

- start the config server:

  `mongod --configsvr --replSet csrs --dbpath /data/db/configdb --port 27018 --fork --logpath log/mongods.log`
- initiate the replica set on the config:

  `mongo localhost:27018 << !
  rs.initiate({_id: "csrs", configsvr: true, members: [{_id: 0, host: "${local_ip}:27018"}]});
  !`
- start the mongod processes:

`mongod --port 27030 --dbpath /data/db/db1-0 --shardsvr --replSet rs --fork --logpath log/mongod1-0.log`

`mongod --port 27040 --dbpath /data/db/db2-0 --shardsvr --replSet rs --fork --logpath log/mongod2-0.log`

`mongod --port 27020 --dbpath /data/db/db0-0 --shardsvr --replSet rs --fork --logpath log/mongod0-0.log`

- initiate the replica set(s)

`mongo localhost:27020 << !
    rs.initiate({_id: "rs", members: [{_id: 0, host: "${local_ip}:27020"}, {_id: 1, host: "${local_ip}:27030"},  {_id: 1, host: "${local_ip}:27040"}]});
    !`

(note, initial script had a separate rs for each shard, which caused the same error)

- start a mongos and point it to the config server:

`mongos --configdb csrs/${local_ip}:27018 --port 27017 --fork --logpath log/mongos.log`

log into the mongos and add shards:

e.g. `sh.addShard("rs/${local_ip}:27020")`.

This last step is where this goes wrong, getting the error

`"errmsg" : "Could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"primary\" } for set rs",
        "code" : 133,`

Can anyone provide any pointers on what I'm missing here?

Comment: The official tool https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch `mlaunch --replicaset --sharded tic tac toe`  will create 3 shards, named tic, tac and toe. Each shard will consist of a replica set of (per default) 3 nodes. It will also create 1 config server and 1 mongos per default.

Comment: In fact, you should add that as an answer so I can accept/approve.

Comment: @AlexBlex Note that `mlaunch` (and the `mtools` scripts) are [not officially supported by MongoDB](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools#disclaimer). Many (but not all) of the contributors do happen to work at MongoDB, but in general this is an open source project (Apache 2.0 licensed) supported by volunteer contributors.

Comment: @Stennie, yes, of course. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the clarification. Shame really they are not supported by the vendor so aggressively, that don't even earn a link in official documentation. They are quite handy and are being used in most of the official university courses.